# When changing path in a ms word field to reference a new file, how can I get it to automatically update/refresh?

Tags: ms-word, field

I have a document with over 1000 images (set a), each of which are sitting on separate folder and I am loading them into my word document by entering the path in a "field". The images get uploaded to the word document and displayed.

I have another 1000 images (set b), all of which are named in the exact same way, except that they all end a different letter (b instead of a). I have tried to take my pre-existing and working word document that displayed the first 1000 images (set a), and edit the path in the field so that they all reference the set b images. This change is easy to make as I just need to find and replace everywhere that the text `image_a.png`appears with `image_b.png`.

However, when I do this, the images don't actually refresh and are instead still displaying all of the images from set a. I have played around with a lot of stuff like saving the document as and opening it again, and for a separate issue I had to enter and exit print preview for my number sequence to update, and I tried that for this issue, but that still doesn't help. The only thing that I have found that works is if I go to each field individually, right click on it and select "edit field" and then select ok, and then the correct image will be displayed. However this is not a practical solution because I would have to do this over 1000 times. Does anyone know what is going on here and does anyone know a way to refresh/update all of the 1000 images at once?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try `Ctrl`+`A` followed by the `F9` key. You may need to press an `Fn` key with the `F9`.

If you need something more nuanced, I can provide a macro. For that, I would need the name of the field being used.

You may want to look at Paul Edstein's tutorial on [relative paths in fields](http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38722-word-fields-relative-paths-external-files.html).

Comment: My tutorial on relative field paths won't help, since the OP's *filenames* differ.